How to overload / customize bash (or any other shell) commands handler?
When in bash some non existing command is run, corresponding error message appears:
$ non-existent-command
non-existent-command: command not found

Is it possible to customize this behavior?
I would like to achieve the following. When the entered command matches, for example, the pattern s\d\d\d, it should be handled specially:

s should be extracted and used as a command,
\d\d\d should be extracted and used as an argument for the s command.
The command created by parsing the above should be run.

This can normally be achieved by means of a function named s that takes the needed arguments. A normal call is used to run such a function. For example:
s 123

But I want to customize the behavior of bash to be able to run such a function with, for example, the following calls:

s123
s500

I tried to find related information in man bash by the following keywords: overload, custom, override and did not succeed.
As I understand it, I need to somehow customize the bash handler that is used for processing input. I did not investigate bash source code to understand if this is feasible.
It will be best to come up with solution that is usable for any shell.
Probably creating a custom bash wrapper/adapter with the needed logic and using it instead of standard bash binary will solve this.

There's already an exposed command_not_found_handle - see Command Search and Execution. This previous question (although zsh focused) might be a good starting point: How to define a function that handles command not found?

It would be interesting to know the reason for this unusual requirement, in case it turns out to be an XY problem.

@gidds the use case is to support convenient saving and loading current working directories as bookmarks by means of super short keystrokes. For example, to save current directory in 1 register the shortcut should be s1 (short for save to 1). To switch to this directory later corresponding shortcut should be l1 (short for load from 1). Registers can be [0-9a-z] as one char or longer. Existing interfering commands like ls should keep their standard behavior. If you familiar with the idea of Vim marks they will be good illustration.

@gidds with standard bash means this can be implemented with s 1, l 1 function calls. But this will 1) occupy l command which I want to continue to use as less alias: alias l='ls -lhA', 2) require to add one more keystrokes (constant typing of space character).

Have you considered a series of aliases, e.g. from something like for i in {1..999}; do alias "l$i=\l $i"; done in your shell startup file?  (The backslash prevents it using your alias for l, which could continue to be aliased to less.)

@gidds It is interesting idea. This particular use case seems will be covered with such approach. But others which require unpredictable user input will not.

@gidds For example, imagine use case with jumping inside existing directories with cd or opening existing files with xdg-open by entering only files/dirs names (without mentioning cd/xdg-open and aliases for them) or even only entering starting parts of the names without performing auto-completion (without pressing tab key). Of course, file name starting part should be enough to resolve disambiguation and automatically choose what user means to open and this input should not collide with existing commands/functions/aliases/scripts.

@gidds Check out the following links with use cases examples: How to change current working directory inside command_not_found_handle, function command_not_found_handle unable to cd/pushd, command_not_found_handler not allowing cd command

In bash:
$ s() { printf 'Called s %s\n' "$*" >&2; }


$ cat $HOME/bin/command_not_found_handle
#!/usr/bin/env bash

command_not_found_handle() {
    if [[ "$*" =~ ^(s)([0-9]{3})$ ]]; then
        "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    else
        printf 'Command not found: %s\n' "$*" >&2
        return 127
    fi
}


$ . $HOME/bin/command_not_found_handle


$ s123
Called s 123

$ s500
Called s 500

$ echo $?
0


$ s5001
Command not found: s5001

$ echo $?
127

FYI 127 is the standard "command not found" exit status. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution for more information.
I'm only using BASH_REMATCH[] as above to call s because I know it's safe to do so given that $* contains the command as a single letter and its args just 3 digits, for anything more complicated see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.
There is no solution that will work in every shell, see How to define a function that handles `command not found`? to find information on approaches to the above for some other shells.
